# DialogFlow Messenger Formatted Text using Custom Payload

Tags: dialogflow-cx

How do we send a formatted text like italicized text to the Dialog Flow Messenger using the Custom Payload

when we try the following Custom Payload, it does not format the text properly,

```
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "description",
        "title": "Description title",
        "text": [
          "This is text line 1.",
          "<I>This is text line 2.</I>"
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello Sabari, did my answer help you?

Comment: Hi Eduardo - It did help. But, we were looking for integrating our Dialogflow CX Agent with the Dialogflow Messenger (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger). Unfortunately we are not using the Facebook Messenger or Slack for our integration. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Sabari, I edited my answer if you could check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be not formatting correctly because you are using a different JSON formatting for a custom payload, your JSON format should look something like this:

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "",
      "payload": {}
    }
  },
  "slack": {
    "text": "",
    "attachments": []
  }
}
```

You can read more about rich responses and custom payloads in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-rich-messages#custom) that Google provides.

Edit: To italicize text, add one asterisk or underscore before and after a word or phrase

```
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "description",
        "title": "Description title",
        "text": [
          "This is text line 1.",
          "_This is text line 2._"
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Eduardo - Thank you for your response! It really helps!, However our requirement is now expanded, it is just not italicized text, we need all sorts of rich text formatting like including bullets, hyperlinks, bold text etc,, for every such response the rich Content payload does not provide an easy option, we have to use accordion type to include all the rich content messages, not sure if there is any other way to achive this with Dialogflow Messenger, we are thinking of building a custom UI. Thank you!